# php session is not redirecting

Tags: php, mysql, session, redirect

I am working with php session as one of my experiment. Trying to learn by developing a script. But I have stacked. I am not quire sure why the php session isn't working.My log in page redirecting my page when i submitting correct email address and password. I am trying to skip log in page if session is set. But its not redirecting. here is the code. Even there has no error log output. So i became so confused what wrong with my code. I am looking for expert suggestion on my experiment.

```
<?php
session_start();
#Working With Session
if (isset($_SESSION['UserId'])) {
    # code...
    header('location:/management/index.php');
exit();
}
require_once("../configuration.php");
#Veriable collected From Login Panel
$Submitted_Email_Address=$_POST['email'];
$Submitted_Password=$_POST['password'];
$encrypt_Submitted_Password=md5($Submitted_Password);

#Lets gather Data From MySql Database
$con=new mysqli($hostname,$dbusername,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email_Address='$Submitted_Email_Address'";
$result=$con->query($query);
$row=$result->fetch_array();
$SQL_Password = $row['Password'];
#LookUp Mysql Database to Get username/user id to store in session
$SQL_UserID=$row['id'];
$SQL_UserName=$row['username'];
$SQL_FirstName=$row['First_Name'];
$SQL_LastName=$row['Last_Name'];
$SQL_Role=$row['Role'];
if ($encrypt_Submitted_Password!=$SQL_Password) {
       echo "Please check your email address and password again";
}
elseif ($encrypt_Submitted_Password == $SQL_Password) {
$_SESSION['UserID']=$GLOBAL['SQL_UserID'];
$_SESSION['UserName']=$GLOBAL['SQL_UserName'];
$_SESSION['FirstName']=$GLOBAL['SQL_FirstName'];
$_SESSION['LastName']=$GLOBAL['SQL_LastName'];
$_SESSION['Role']=$GLOBAL['SQL_Role'];
header('location:/management/index.php');
}

#Lets CLose All The MySql Connection
$result->free();
$con->close();
?>
```

After that i tried to see if the session is not set then redirect the page. but its not redirecting. I tried the following code to check if the session is not set let redirect the page. but not redirecting

```
session_start();
    #Working With Session
    if (!isset($_SESSION['UserId'])) {
        # code...
        header('location:/management/index.php');
    exit();
    }
```

Comment: `header("Location: /management/index.php");`

Comment: why are you using `$GLOBAL`? The variable are **RIGHT THERE** to start with... And you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and also don't bother checking if your query succeeded. If the query fails, you still blindly fetch a value and probably stuff null/undefined values into the session, trashing whatever you had in there to start with.

Comment: In the elseif ($encrypt_Submitted_Password == $SQL_Password) area i used the same header . so its working on that part and redirecting when i submitting correct email and password. but its not redirecting either the session is set or not set. 
I tried with the header("Location: /management/index.php"); but still no luck

Comment: This is full of problems. **MD5** is completely useless as a password encrypting function, **DO NOT** use it. You're putting `$_POST` data directly in your query creating a gigantic [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/) because you're not [properly escaping user data](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Placeholder values should be used whenever possible to ensure your data is handled correctly. You urgently need to [read a guide on how to use PHP properly](http://phptherightway.com/).

Comment: @tadman I am very beginer. i am just understanding the communication between php and mysql. I know i have to use mysqli_escape_string() function to avoid sql injection. Thanks for your warning dear. :)

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You really don't need to be calling the escape functions manually unless you're doing something really unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are missing something so silly. your code seems that its a php file which gather email address and password from a login page and validate it and then redirect it two another page. 
I think your login page (might be login.html, access.html) is not redirecting. So your should put this following php code block in the login page. not here in the login.php which is only used to validate the inputed data. Happy coding and keep your mind calm. :)
and you have to use **'UserID'** not **'UserId'**

```
session_start();
#Working With Session
if (isset($_SESSION['UserID'])) {
    # code...
    header('location:/management/index.php');
exit();
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness. I really did the mistake what you said. Now its working. So shame on me. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your `header` call:

```
header('Location: /management/index.php'); // notice capitalization and spacing; they matter.
```

Comment: I have changed it to 
header('Location: /management/index.php');
but no luck @Ed cottrell

Answer (score 0):

Remove "!" from isset or put redirect in else clause:

eg:

```
   session_start();
        #Working With Session
        if (**!**isset($_SESSION['UserId'])) {
            # code...
            header('location:/management/index.php');
        exit();
        }
```